# How to specify which public key file to use with a repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, gnupg, signature

I am trying to set up a repo on local file system on ubuntu. I will use that repo only during the installation of my product & then remove the repo. 
Now I want to have my deb packages signed & verified while I install my product (i.e., when I do "apt install " from this repo), the system must first verify the gpg signature and only then install the deb. And I want other repo to keep working as usual, i.e., if they were using insecure repos, let them keep using those.

I just want to add authentication to this one repo. 
Now I have gone through commands like `apt-key add <local-path-to-key>`. does it apply to all available repos? How do we know to which repo does this key apply to? I want this key to be applied to a specific repo. Is there any way to mention that.

(In RHEL, there is a provision for this. Like in /etc/yum.repos.d/private.repo,

[prod-noarch]

name=Product

baseurl=file:/root/path

```
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-prod-release
```

gpgcheck=1

enabled=1
)

Does ubuntu have some option like this?

Comment: does anyone has any idea on this?